# Re Installing Managed package in Developer edition

Tags: managed-package, package, unmanaged-package, beta-managed-package, package-install

1. I have created a managed package **"SamplePack"** in my developer
   edition "Dev1".
2. **SamplePack** is installed in another developer edition "Dev2", It's working fine too.
3. Now i Uninstalled **SamplePack** from "**Dev2**". Again I'm trying
   to re install same package into "**Dev2**".
4. It's throwing an error **"This app can't be installed. Package Not
   Found: "The requested package doesn't exist or has been deleted.
   Please contact package publisher"**

What actually stopping to re install **SamplePack** Managed package

or

Can't we re install a manged Package Once we Uninstalled

Comment: If the destination org is on a different pod than the packaging org and you tried to install soon after creating the package, it may not have propagated to all the pods yet. Wait a little bit and try it again. Could also be that you copied the installation URL incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to suggest me that ,your Publisher org has depreciated the package or deleted .

Because this error only pops if you no longer have the package in your Publisher org .

And to answer we can certainly uninstall and install managed packages as many times as we need .

Comment: Thank you for reply @Mohith I forgot to mention One point, i.e..,  **the same package able to install in new Developer edition for first time**.  It means Package exists I hope soo. AND **more over depricate button disabled for that package version**.

Comment: This seems timing issue .Also can you try with different browser and some delay like half an hour

Comment: I have tried to install yesterday, error came. I'm trying today also getting the same error.

Comment: Sounds like you will need support case on this . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if package is managed-release or managed-beta.
managed-beta package cannot be upgraded.

Comment: The user is installing and uninstalling the app not upgrading

Comment: i..e.., ** managed-release**. and I'm not upgrading the package. I have Uninstalled the package and trying to re install the same package there I'm getting above error

Comment: Exactly @Mohith, The user is **uninstalling and  installing** the app not upgrading